# compilation programming using yacc

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc

So I have a yacc file which gives the required yy.tab.c when I compile it, but when I use cc or gcc to compile the output file with the library -ly, it says ly not found.

I've installed and reinstalled yacc,  what could the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

The path to liby.a could be wrong, or you do not have liby.a installed.
Try locating it by executing:

$ find / -name liby.a

and then add the path to your compile statement

$ gcc *.c -ly -L/path/to/lib/

Comment: Yeah so  it can't find them...which is weird cause I installed byacc using synaptic. Should I re install?

Comment: Yeah you could try to reinstall.
Look for dev-packages of yacc in synaptic.
If it does not work, download yacc by your own and compile it by your own.

Comment: byacc doesn't come with (or need) -ly, though you do need to provide your own `yyerror` and `main` functions.